# openssl connect including full path on host site

Tags: encryption, openssl

I am trying to verify the cipher suites that are being offered by my web server is restricted to only secure ciphers.
There are several different sites running on the server (using different web servers).

How can I specify the full URL including the path to the site I'm testing?

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect 10.10.10.63:443/sites/mySiteA
getaddrinfo: Servname not supported for ai_socktype
connect:errno=0
```

Comment: You don't need a URL to verify the ciphers, just use `openssl s_client -connect 10.10.10.63:443` and if you need to specify the name of the server than also add `-servername myservername` option.

Comment: Hey, my example also only answers on a specific deep link with a certificate, i.e. I cannot connect via IP only. How can one use `s_client` in this scenario?